# Why is my terminal displaying my IP address beside my name?

Tags: terminal

Well, I was just wondering if it is okay for the OS X shell to display something like this:

```
192-168-1-7:~ name$
```

What does the above actually mean? I have tried setting my host name but still didn't work!

And the Terminal window is name is `name--- bash ---80x24`
What does that mean?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't that where the shell would normally put the name of the computer?  Maybe it did not figure out a computer name, so it used the IP address as a default.

Comment: bash is the name of the shell being used.   80x24 means the terminal is set to 24 lines of 80 characters each.

Comment: Type `echo $PS1`  as well as `uname -n` and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

The bash interactive shell prompt - if not tweeked further - is determined by the PS1-line in the file /etc/bashrc.

The 6th line `PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '` decodes to

- `\h` the hostname up to the first `.' - in your case **192-168-1-7**
- `:` delimiter
- `\W` the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde - in your case **~** which is equivalent to the directory /Users/name/
- delimiter/space
- `\u` short user name of the current user - in your case **name**
- `$` UserID-identifier (it turns to a # if the effective UID is 0 (~root) - else $)
- delimiter/space

A longer list of possible customizations of the prompt (e.g. time, date, bell) will be shown after opening Terminal.app, entering `man bash` and going down to PROMPTING.

---

The Terminal window title shows your working directory, the name of your shell  (bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell) and its size: 80 characters x 24 lines.

---

Your fully qualified host name is probably 192-168-1-7.SLD.TLD (e.g. 192-168-1-7.dlink.home) and is assigned by a DHCP server in your network. Considering all that your Terminal window name and the embedded shell prompt is completely regular.